# Imprimir todas as páginas geradas pelo PHP e MYSQL

Tags: php, html, mysql, html5

Olá, estou fazendo um extrato no qual pode ser gerado diversas páginas, utilizei um sistema bem simples de paginação utilzando `limit` nas **querys** do **mysql**.

O problema é que é gerado várias páginas e na hora de imprimir ele apenas imprimi uma de cada vez (o que é o certo já que são páginas diferentes), porém teria alguma forma de imprimir todas essas páginas? Já que eu gero uma url "esperada" como: page=1, page=2, page=3 e assim por diante, teria como imprimir todas as páginas geradas? Pois tenho uma `$var` que contém o número de páginas geradas pela query. Teria alguma solução para isso? Ou terei que repensar esse sistema de paginação?

Comment: você terá que criar uma chamada diferente para a impressão, gerando a página com o conteúdo completo como quer...

Comment: No caso estou utilizando uma div para delimitar a área para imprimir, teria que atribuir um valor da page à ela e então chamar todas de uma vez? <a href="javascript:printDiv('imprimirext')" >

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problema resolvido com o plugin DataTables, que no meu caso caiu bem já que ele possui várias funções e uma delas é fazer a paginação Client Side, sendo assim consigo gerar todos os resultados de uma vez, assim como imprimi-los.
Se alguém passar pelo mesmo problema aqui está o link: [Data tables](https://datatables.net/)

Tive que reformular um pouco meu sistema para conseguir fazer funcionar porém ele é bem simples de se utilizar e configurar, assim como implementar ainda mais funçoes.